# How do I recursively watch file changes in Rust?

Tags: linux, rust

How to watch for file/directory changes in Rust and how to integrate this in a non-blocking way?  The canonical example (such as that provided by https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.15/notify/), shows how to watch the files, but it will block the rest of your main function execution.  (I'm pursuing this https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)

Answer (score 28):

The [example code](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/index.html#examples) for the `notify` crate shows how to do what you want. It uses `RecursiveMode::Recursive` to specify watching all files and subdirectories within the provided path.

```
use notify::{Watcher, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res| {
        match res {
           Ok(event) => println!("event: {:?}", event),
           Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
        }
    })?;

    // Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    watcher.watch(Path::new("."), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I wonder how to let the main function return the changed string rather than just print it out.

Comment: @ShuangSong Why would you like to return it from the main function? You could just pass it to another function that handles the change.